# Connecting MongoDB Atlas to remote MongoDB server?

Tags: mongodb, virtual-machine, mongodb-atlas

I'm new to MongoDB and I wanted to ask that whether can I connect a remote MongoDB service to MongoDB Atlas.

I have a remote MongoDB service running in my company's Azure VM and was able to connect to the service in my local machine using MongoDB Compass.

However, my seniors are more concerned about whether can they use MongoDB atlas to view the analytic statistics of the remote MongoDB server. But I cant find any way to use MongoDB Atlas to connect to the remote MongoDB service.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect by following two ways from your shell:-

1. mongo <server_ip>:27017/dbname -u username -p password
2. mongo --host <server_ip> --port 27017

   show dbs

   use dbname

   db.auth("username", "password")